# how to visit each Entity's property when `serializer.pre_serialize` event is raised

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-2.8, jms-serializer

I would like to visit recursively each property of the serializing Entity,  check if a string is set and verify that the metadata property is properly set to `string`, otherwise change it in order to allow the serialization.

Imagine a `users` property which is an `ArrayCollection`, but I force the value to be a string in corner cases.

I set a `SerializationSubscriber` to catch the `serializer.pre_serialize` event, but I'm not finding any doc for take advantage of the `Visitor` and surroundings.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyEventSubscriber implements JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 'method' => 'onPreSerialize'),
        );
    }

    public function onPreSerialize(JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        /*
         * @var YourEntity $object
         */
        $object = $event->getObject();
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($foo);
        $props = $reflect->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

        foreach ($props as $prop) {
            $method = 'get'.ucfirst($prop->getName());

            // here is call of methods like getId(), getName() etc,
            // depending on name of entity properties
            $object->$method();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ouch! via reflection? Quite expensive, isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately is not recursive: what I really would need is visiting each property and change the type if needed. Since there's no event to catch that moment of visiting a node, I should re-visit all the entity's property the way JMSSerialize follows. Quite expensive I'd say